# map is not rendered using mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox, coords

I'm using mapbox to make a map. I don't know if my map is being rendered or not cause the only i could see on the screen is the pointer and i can't even open the console to read the mistake. Please help me to find out if there's anything wrong with my codes! Thank you so much:

My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.3.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
  <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.3.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />

  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }

    #map {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='map'></div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My JS:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZGh0NzZkeThjIiwiYSI6ImNrdjd0Zm92cDF4aGMyb2wwenhtbWJidjUifQ.KUBtTY1kI2SOMFXkKeerWQ';

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successLocation, errorLocation, {
    enableHighAccuracy: true
})

function successLocation(position) {
    console.log(position)
    setupMap([position.coords.longtitude, position.coords.latitude])
}

function errorLocation() {

}

function setupMap(center) {
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
        center: center
    });
}
```

Comment: please edit the question and hide the `accessToken`

Comment: What is the "mistake"? and why can't you open the dev tools to see it?